# Problem playing video playlist in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i making a program that plays a video when it matches with a word that a person says, if it matches, the video shows in a tkinter label.My problem is when it matches more than one word, because the program plays all the videos that matches at once.I want to play all the videos that matches with the words one after another.Im using tkinter and tkvideo . Hope you can help me with this one.

```
dir = 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Prototipo\\palabras'
listaVid = []
with os.scandir(dir) as ficheros:
     for fichero in ficheros:
            listaVid.append(fichero.name.replace('.mp4',''))


def audioTexto():
    listener = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:
        print("Escuchando...")
        audio = listener.listen(source)
        rec = listener.recognize_whisper(audio, language="spanish")
        trans_tab = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, u'\u0301\u0308'), None)
        rec = normalize('NFKC', normalize('NFKD', rec).translate(trans_tab))
        rec = re.sub(r'[.]', '', rec)
        palabras = rec.split(',')
    try:
        for palabra in palabras:
            for vid in listaVid:
                if vid in palabra:
                    player = tkvideo.tkvideo('C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Reconocimiento de voz\\palabras\\'+vid+'.mp4', lblVid,loop=0, size = (640,360))
                    player.play()
                                     
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("No se entiende")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("error")

root =Tk()
btnHablar = Button(root,text='Hablar..',command= audioTexto)
btnHablar.grid(column=0, row=0 , padx=5 ,pady=5)
lblVid = Label(root)
lblVid.grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the required videos in a list and go through the list one by one.

In order to play the videos one by one, you can overload the class method `load()` of `tkvideo` to signal the application using *virtual event* when the current playing video ends.  When the application receives the virtual event, it can start the next video.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkvideo

# create custom class based on tkvideo
class Player(tkvideo.tkvideo):
    # overload load()
    def load(self, path, label, loop):
        # call the original load()
        super().load(path, label, loop)
        # video ended, signal the application via virtual event
        label.event_generate("<<End>>")

# function to play a video in the playlist
def play():
    try:
        # get next video from the playlist
        video = next(playlist)
        print(f"{video=}")
        # play the video
        player = Player(video, playbox)
        player.play()
    except Exception as ex:
        # no more video to play
        print(f"{ex=}")

# create the playlist
playlist = iter(["1.mp4", "2.mp4", "3.mp4"])

root = tk.Tk()
playbox = tk.Label(root)
playbox.pack()
# call play() upon receiving virtual event "<<End>>"
playbox.bind("<<End>>", lambda e: play())
# play the first video
play()
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will play a video immediately for every matching video. Simply remove `play` from the loop.

```
for palabra in palabras:
    for vid in listaVid:
        if vid in palabra:
            # you are doing this on every iteration of the loops
            player = tkvideo.tkvideo('C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Reconocimiento de voz\\palabras\\'+vid+'.mp4', lblVid, loop=0, size = (640,360))
            player.play()
```

Do something like this, instead:

```
VIDEO_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Reconocimiento de voz\\palabras\\{}.mp4'

# create a queue of video paths for word
queue = [VIDEO_PATH.format(vid) for palabra in palabras for vid in listaVid if vid in palabra]

# get first path
video = queue[0] # or queue.pop(0)

# init player
player = tkvideo.tkvideo(video, lblVid, loop=0, size = (640,360))

# play
player.play()
```

It seems to me that this makes more sense for finding videos, but only you know how these things are actually formatted

```
queue = [VIDEO_PATH.format(palabra) for palabra in palabras if palabra in listaVid]
```

---

##### Creating a trigger for next playlist item

In order to play the `queue` as a playlist, the easiest thing to do is to modify `tkvideo`. First modify the `__init__` method to accept a callback.

```
def __init__(self, path, label, loop = 0, size = (640,360), hz = 0, callback = None):
    #... everything that is already in this method
    self.callback = callback
```

Then call the `callback` at the end of `load`. This way, when the video is over you'll get a "heads up" and can play the next video.

```
def load(self, path, label, loop, hz):
    #... everything that is already in this method
              
    if callable(self.callback):              
        self.callback()
```

##### usage

```
from tkvideo import tkvideo
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.config(**kwargs)
        self.geometry('800x600')
        
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.viewer = tk.Label(self)
        self.viewer.grid(sticky='nswe')

        self.playlist = ['one.mp4', 'two.mp4', 'three.mp4']
        self.next_vid() # start playing the playlist
        
    def next_vid(self):
        if self.playlist:
            player = tkvideo(self.playlist.pop(0), self.viewer, loop=0, size=(800,600), callback=self.next_vid)
            player.play()
        else:
            print('playlist consumed')
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

---

If you are going to dig around in `tkvideo` and modify it, I would suggest adding a method that can handle an entire playlist. All the parts to do that are right here in this post. You just need to move some things around and change how they are referenced.

You may want to consider that `tkvideo` does not play sound so, you are basically treating mp4's like a gif. Due to the delay in load time between videos it would likely make more sense to turn your mp4s into gifs, and learn how to play gifs, instead.

Comment: But that only plays one video, i want to play all the videos that matches with the words one after another

Comment: @BastianCastillo - Yeah, so just get to work on creating a listener that knows when the video is complete, and when it is triggered, play the next item in the queue. The point here is: you never had a playlist you were just throwing everything at the player. The queue in my answer is the playlist.

Comment: @BastianCastillo - I updated my answer to show you one way that you could implement a playlist.